# Reproduzir videos do youtube em uma aplicação Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Olá, eu estou criando um aplicativo para o Windows Phone 8/8.1 programando em C#, um dos recursos será a possibilidade de ver vídeos do youtube, porem não consegui fazer com que isso funcione usando o MediaElement. Há outra forma de se consegui ? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a classe YouTube que está disponível na biblioteca MyToolkit para Windows Phone, dê uma olhada:

https://github.com/RSuter/MyToolkit/wiki/YouTube

Exemplo para reproduzir um vídeo do YouTube usando um MediaElement, mas utilizando o método GetVideoUriAsync: O XAML com o MediaElement:

O XAML com MediaElement:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="player" Width="480" Height="320" />
```

O código para iniciar o vídeo no player (por exemplo, em um botão clicado):

```
var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(youTubeId, YouTubeQuality.Quality720P);
if (url != null)
{
    player.Source = url.Uri;
    player.Play();
}
else
    // TODO show error (video uri não existe)
```

Comment: seu link foi trocado do Codeplex pro GitHub pois o primeiro está sendo desativado. Está sendo feito um esforço conjunto pela mudança: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6317/codeplex-ser%C3%A1-desativado-no-dia-25-12-2017-que-tal-atualizarmos-os-links . Caso o link que usei foi inapropriado, favor escolher um que o seja mas que não venha do Codeplex. Grata.

Comment: @carla obrigado. bjus